# Numpy: Mask of elements in array1 that are also elements of array2

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder if there is a numpy natural way of creating a binary mask over array1 for elements that are also in array2. Another way to say it, binary mask over array1 for intersection of array1 and 2.

This works:

```
def bin_mask(a, b):
    return sum(a==n for n in b)

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,20])
b = np.array([3,5,7])

In: bin_mask(a,b)
Out: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

But I wonder if there is some numpy prebuilt I am missing.

Edit:
Correct answer from comments: np.isin(a, b). I also marked in1d as the correct answer. Both work.

Comment: `np.isin(a, b).view('i1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[in1d](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) method does the trick too:

```
>>> np.in1d(a,b)
array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False])
>>> np.in1d(a,b).astype(int)    
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```